# Powershell: You cannot call a null-valued expression

Tags: powershell, copy

Hello Stack Overflow Community,

at the moment I'm struggling with this code (it's not that beautiful):

```
$filepath = "C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles"
$filearchivepath = "C:\inetpub\logs"
$daystoarchive = 1
$_ = "";

function create-7zip([String] $aDirectory, [String] $aZipfile){
    #change the path where you downloaded the 7z exe
    [string]$pathToZipExe = "C:\Users\kschweiger\Downloads\7za.exe";
    [Array]$arguments = "a", "-tzip", "$aZipfile", "$aDirectory";
    & $pathToZipExe $arguments;
}


#Create a new folder with the specific date
$ArchiveFolder = (Get-Date -Format dd.MM.yyyy) + " - Logs-Archive"
if(Test-Path "$filearchivepath\$ArchiveFolder"){
    Write-Host "Folder already exists!"
}else{
    New-Item -Path $filearchivepath -Name $ArchiveFolder -ItemType directory
}


#Save alle files older than X days into $Files
$Files = Get-ChildItem -Path $filepath -Recurse | where {$_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-$daystoarchive)}

#Copy/Move files and keep folder structure
foreach ($File in $Files){

    $NewPath = $File.DirectoryName.Replace($filepath,"")

    if (!(Test-Path "$filearchivepath\$ArchiveFolder\$NewPath"))
    {
        New-Item -Path "$filearchivepath\$ArchiveFolder\$NewPath" -ItemType Directory
    }

    $File | Copy-Item -Destination "$filearchivepath\$ArchiveFolder\$NewPath"
}

#Compress folder
if(Test-Path "$filearchivepath\$ArchiveFolder.zip"){
    Write-Host "Archive-File already exists!"
}else{
    #[IO.Compression.ZipFile]::CreateFromDirectory("$filearchivepath\$ArchiveFolder","$filearchivepath\$ArchiveFolder.zip")
    create-7zip "$filearchivepath\$ArchiveFolder"  "$filearchivepath\$ArchiveFolder.zip"
    #Delete Folder
    Remove-Item -Path "$filearchivepath\$ArchiveFolder" -Recurse -Force
}
```

The code works. but I also get a error message called:

> You cannot call a null-valued expression

[image: Error Message]

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Add `-File` to your `Get-ChildItem` to exclude folders (they have no `DirectoryName`).

Comment: @KevinSchweiger: Fortunately, robdy seems to have spotted your problem, but in the future please consider posting a [MCVE] (or as close as you can get to one) to reduce the amount of code in the question. This makes it easier for potential answerers as well as future readers to understand the problem.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I already had the added -File to this line. But if I do so, the programm doesnt work at all and I get the error message "A parameter cannot be found that mateches parameter name "File".

Comment: On my Windows 10 PC it works fine but on the Windows Web Server 2008 R2 not

Comment: BTW It doesn't make sense to initialize the automatic variable `$_` which is only accessible in a pipe to reference the currently processed object. See `Get-Help about_Automatic_Variables`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Get-ChildItem` by default returns files and folders. If you need only files, you should use `-File`. Otherwise, your `$Files` will contain folders too (as they have `LastWriteTime` property).

If you try to run `.DirectoryName.Replace($filepath,"")` on a folder, it'll return such error as you cannot run replacing on `$null`.

**Update:** for PowerShell 2.0 you can use `| where { ! $_.PSIsContainer }` ([source](https://superuser.com/a/150762/913590))

---

#### How can I troubleshoot it by myself?

In your error you can see which line is broken:

```
$NewPath = $File.DirectoryName.Replace($filepath,"")
```

All you have to do to troubleshoot such situations is to list all the involved variables and check their values. You could do it like this:

```
$File
$File.DirectoryName
Pause

$NewPath = $File.DirectoryName.Replace($filepath,"")
```

Using `Pause` can be useful as it'll wait for you to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> before continuing.

Comment: Thank you for the quick respone. But if I add the -File cmd like this:$Files = Get-ChildItem -Path $filepath -Recurse -File | where {$_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-$daystoarchive)} - I get a new error message:A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name File

Comment: What version of PowerShell are you using? `$PSVersionTable.PSVersion`

Comment: Major 2 - Minor 0 - Build -1 - Revision -1

Comment: Then I strongly suggest to update it. Anyway, I added the workaround for PS 2.0 to my answer. Please mark it as accepted if it's helpful to you. Thanks!